# Alfresco swsdp initial creation

Tags: alfresco

I am using alfresco-allinone-archetype 2.0, and I have to listen to NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy for new site creation.
My question is, when I tried to get preset of new site to find out is it newly created site specific type I got a problem.
Code for that is:

```
public void onCreateNode(ChildAssociationRef ref) {
          NodeRef siteNode = ref.getChildRef();
          String presets = (String)                   nodeService.getProperty(siteNode,SiteModel.PROP_SITE_PRESET);
          if (mySitePresets.equals(presets)){
                  doSomething();
          }
}
```

The issue is just for initially created site, swsdp, for some reason nodeService.getProperty breaks and said that couldn't apply all patches.
Does someone had same problem?
Do you have some advice for me?

I attached my console output of errors.
Thanks in advance.

```
2015-04-16 17:07:14,509  ERROR [admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [localhost-startStop-1] 03160007 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03160006 Failed to execute transaction-level behaviour public abstract void org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies$OnCreateNodePolicy.onCreateNode(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ChildAssociationRef) in transaction c3c9abd9-16cd-46d1-b632-3976cd36828d
    at org.alfresco.repo.policy.TransactionBehaviourQueue.execute(TransactionBehaviourQueue.java:257)
    at org.alfresco.repo.policy.TransactionBehaviourQueue.beforeCommit(TransactionBehaviourQueue.java:134)
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(TransactionSupportUtil.java:535)
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(TransactionSupportUtil.java:514)
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.beforeCommit(TransactionSupportUtil.java:479)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:925)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:738)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.SpringAwareUserTransaction.commit(SpringAwareUserTransaction.java:482)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:476)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.applyWithTxns(AbstractPatch.java:455)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.access$000(AbstractPatch.java:58)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch$4.doWork(AbstractPatch.java:613)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch$4.doWork(AbstractPatch.java:610)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.apply(AbstractPatch.java:617)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.apply(AbstractPatch.java:579)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl$PatchWork.applyPatch(PatchServiceImpl.java:556)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl$PatchWork.execute(PatchServiceImpl.java:468)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl.applyPatch(PatchServiceImpl.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl.applyPatchAndDependencies(PatchServiceImpl.java:300)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchServiceImpl.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.applyOutstandingPatches(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:76)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:124)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:120)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.InvalidNodeRefException: Node does not exist: workspace://SpacesStore/4c2fdbda-9981-4dda-98fb-75c66bb9377b (status:Status[id=580changeTxnId=c3c9abd9-16cd-46d1-b632-3976cd36828d, dbTxnId=8, deleted=true])
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.getNodePairNotNull(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:182)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.hasAspect(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:997)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.lock.mem.LockableAspectInterceptor.invoke(LockableAspectInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.hasAspect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.invoke(MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.hasAspect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.service.StoreRedirectorProxyFactory$RedirectorInvocationHandler.invoke(StoreRedirectorProxyFactory.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.hasAspect(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.getPivotNodeRef(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:162)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.DisableAuditableBehaviourInterceptor.invoke(DisableAuditableBehaviourInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor$1.execute(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:454)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor.invoke(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at it.qbreng.pec.behaviour.CreateSiteBehaviour.onCreateNode(CreateSiteBehaviour.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour$JavaMethodInvocationHandler.invoke(JavaBehaviour.java:174)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.onCreateNode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.policy.TransactionBehaviourQueue.execute(TransactionBehaviourQueue.java:245)
    ... 60 more

 2015-04-16 17:07:14,681  INFO  [admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [localhost-startStop-1] 
=== Applied patch                 === 
ID: patch.db-V3.4-UsageTables
RESULT: 
Script completed
=====================================
 2015-04-16 17:07:14,681  INFO  [admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [localhost-startStop-1] 
=== Applied patch                 === 
ID: patch.db-V4.0-TenantTables
RESULT: 
Script completed
=====================================
 2015-04-16 17:07:14,681  INFO  [admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [localhost-startStop-1] 
=== Applied patch                 === 
ID: patch.db-V3.4-JBPM-varinst-indexes
RESULT: 
Script completed
=====================================
 2015-04-16 17:07:14,682  INFO  [admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [localhost-startStop-1] 
=== Applied patch                 === 
ID: patch.db-V5.0-ContentUrlEncryptionTables
RESULT: 
Script completed
=====================================
 2015-04-16 17:07:14,682  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03160008 Not all patches could be applied
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:111)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:124)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:120)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Apr 16, 2015 5:07:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03160008 Not all patches could be applied
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:111)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:124)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:120)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 16, 2015 5:07:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextListener
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03160008 Not all patches could be applied
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:111)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:124)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:120)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you injecting `nodeService` or `NodeService` as your bean? (They're not the same...)

Comment: thanks for reply Garvarr, can you explain me what is difference between these two?

Comment: I am using NodeService, it looks like nodeService is not ready in that moment of creating swsdp and that cause exceptions.

Comment: It is same behaviour with nodeService and NodeService. Maybe is something wrong with NodeRef siteNode, what you think?

Comment: You know the SWSDP aka Sample Site is an ACP which gets imported. You can specify sample.site.disabled=true in the global properties to disable it. If normal site creation do succeed I shouldn't bother too much on this.

Comment: Thanks Malik, you are right, I can disable **swsdp** from global properties and everything works fine. It's good enough solution for me.